# Assigning macros in VBA form control and active x control combo box

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm trying to assign macros to an active x combo box I already did the form control version and it works but when I try the same thing on active x I keep getting errors, what am I missing?

The listfillrange are on the selected cells with 30_06_16 and 29_06_16 and display fine is just when you click on the list with any date, an error appears

Macro1:30_06_16
Macro2:29_06_16

form control combo box:

```
Sub DropDown13_Change()
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Drop Down 13").ControlFormat
    Select Case .List(.Value)
    Case "30_06_2016": 30_06_16
    Case "29_06_2016": 29_06_16
    End Select
  End With  
End Sub
```

active x combo box:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Combo Box 2").ControlFormat
    Select Case .List(.Value)
    Case "30_06_2016": Bank_Prompt_30_06_16
    Case "29_06_2016": Bank_Prompt_29_06_16
    End Select
  End With  
End Sub
```

form control is fine just active x, probably missing something obvious but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The syntax for ActiveX is completely different:

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ComboBox2
    Select Case .List(.ListIndex)
      Case "30_06_2016": Bank_Prompt_30_06_16 
      Case "29_06_2016": Bank_Prompt_29_06_16
    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if i was to do this in a userform would it be the same?